# How to swap using different data types

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, swap, words

Ok so lets suppose I have an array of 4 ints ==

```
int[] input = new int[]{1,2,3,4};

//now I some how converted these numbers into words and gets an array:-
String Str = new String[]{one,two,three,four};
//then I run a sort method on Str.
Arrays.sort(Str);
//and I got this array in the end  ::: {four,one,three,two}
```

Now i want to reconvert it into numbers(int) so that my final result should look like this:- {4,1,3,2}

In Summery :-
I want to sort the input int arrays through its English(words)representation

> Examples :-

```
[input]      [convert to words]         [sorting]             [Result]
```

> {1,2,3,4} => {one,two,three,four} =>{four,one,three,two} => 4,1,3,2
>
> {55,23,3,45} =>{fifty five, twenty three, three, fourty five} => {fifty five, fourty five, three, twenty three} => {55,45,3,23}

so, uptill now I manage to convert the inputs into words and sort it but I dont know how to convert the `Str array` back to its original int array as showen in the examples above...

> THE REAL QUESTION :- I know i can convert it using loops and
>   array..but i wanna know is it possible to do it using array swapping??[maybe
>   through its indexes??]

P.s:- Sorry for any in convenience I may cause to you. and thanks in advance

Comment: With a few assumptions, yes it is possible. You should probably start by implementing your own sort, then when you swap the elements in the word array - also swap the elements in your number array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following..

1. instead of storing separately you can create a class and store that.

   ```
   public class Numbers {
   String word;
   Integer digit;

   public Numbers(String w, int d) {
       word = w;
       digit = d;
   }
   ```

   }
2. use `Arrays.sort` and create your custom comparator

   ```
   Arrays.sort(n, new Comparator<Numbers>() {
       public int compare(Numbers word, Numbers o) {
           return word.digit.compareTo((o.digit));
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to convert `int` to `String`,
Just use your "intToWord" fucntion in comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(n, new Comparator<Integer>() {
  public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
      return intToWord(a).compareTo(intToWord(b));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have already translated the numbers into words, and you're having problems translating them back.

Create a map with key,value pair like `{"one","1"},{"two","2"}` when you are doing the conversion in the first part.  Then just use that map to convert the sorted results back.